# Is it possible to know if sums of powers of a number is divisible by another number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Is there a way to find whether a number (say $A$) formed by summing powers of another number (say $B$) is divisible by another number $C$? $A$ is a number like, for example, $B^1+B^3$. We can use a power of $B$ at most one time.

I don't want to know the number $A$. I just want to know that is $A$ is divisible by $C$.

Any help is appreciated.

edit: i found out that the answer is always yes :D

Comment: that is, for example A can not be B^2+B^2. i just can include B^2 once. or i don't include it at all

Comment: but if there is not such a number i will do infinitely many calculations. i dont want to know that if a number is divisible by C. i want to know that can i write a number formed from sums of powers of B that is divisible by C. i want to answer the question that is there a number A?

Comment: Having shared your question with us, and having found an answer to your question, maybe you want to share your answer with us?

Answer (score 1):

If B and C are coprime, $B^{\phi(c)}=1 \pmod C$, where $\phi(n)$ is [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totient).  In this case there is always such an A, take $\sum_{i=1}^CB^{i\phi(C)}$.  If they are not coprime I believe you can do this with the $B/gcd(B,C)$